# Get the content of dataTransfer.getData('Text')); and compare them

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

What i want to do is, get the data which i gather with dataTransfer.getData('Text'));
and see which message it contains, in order to do the appropriate things in want to do.

Consider the following code.

```
document.getElementById('droppable').addEventListener('dragenter', function (e) { e.preventDefault() });
document.getElementById('droppable').addEventListener('dragover', function (e) { e.preventDefault() });
document.getElementById('droppable').addEventListener('drop', function (e) { 
    var a = e.dataTransfer.getData('Text'));
    if (a == "white"){
        alert("white!!");
    }
    else{
        alert("black!!");
    }

    e.preventDefault(); });

var draggables = document.querySelectorAll('[draggable=true]');

for (var i = 0; i < draggables.length; i++) {
    draggables[i].addEventListener("dragstart", function (e) { e.dataTransfer.setData('Text', this.getAttribute('data')); });
}
```

Care to point what am missing with the check condition?

Comment: And what is wrong with your code? Describe your issue please. Does `this.getAttribute('data')` returns expected value?

Comment: I don't get any alerts. Considering if the first "IF" fails, the "else" would proc. Without using getData(..), just by texting the drag and drop and using alerts, my code works.

Comment: so you mean the drop event is not fired?! Any error in console?EDIT: you have an extra parenthesis here: `var a = e.dataTransfer.getData('Text'));` It should be: `var a = e.dataTransfer.getData('Text');`

Comment: It works perfectly. What i want to do though, is to distinguish which element has been dropped, and this was my approach.

Comment: Excellent, i can't believe it was just this minor detail. Thank you and have a happy Sunday!

Comment: You too, glad you have fixed your issue! ;)